# What is the API to do search like on start button in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, api, search, full-text-search

What is the API to do search like the one available on Start menu button? Is it always available on windows 7?

Comment: See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a quick overflow + links to sample code.

Comment: Why don't you write an answer? :)

Comment: Because it's not an answer. It's a hint.